# Date Range From Single Date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I need to create a date range based on a date from a monthly file with the results grouped by EmpID and StatusCode.

The "start" date would be the beginnning of the earliest month and "end" would be the last day of the month for the last month in the grouping. Thank you!

Table:

```
EmpID   StatusCode  AsOF
12345   J   6/30/2014
12345   J   7/31/2014
12345   J   8/29/2014
12345   J   9/30/2014
12345   G   10/31/2014
12345   G   11/28/2014
12345   G   12/31/2014
12345   G   1/30/2015
12345   G   2/27/2015
12345   M   3/30/2015
12345   M   4/30/2015
12345   M   5/29/2015
12345   M   6/30/2015
12345   G   7/31/2015
12345   G   8/31/2015
12345   G   9/30/2015
12345   G   10/30/2015
12345   G   11/30/2015
```

Expected Result:

```
EmpID   StatusCode  Start   End
12345   J   6/1/2014    9/30/2014
12345   G   10/1/2014   2/28/2015
12345   M   3/1/2015    6/30/2015
12345   G   7/1/2015    11/30/2015
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Answer (score 2):

The `group by` logic is not only dependent on `EmpID` and `StatusCode` (as stated in the question) but also dependent on what is called [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands). For example, the expected output has 2 records for `EmpID` 12345 and `StatusCode` G because there are 2 islands (2014/10 - 2015/2 and 2015/7 - 2015/11) and a gap between them being (2015/3 - 2015/6).

**Sample Data:**

I used the sample data that @RazvanSocol was so nice to type up, but including it here just in case his answer gets modified later.

```
CREATE TABLE #sample_Data (
    EmpID int NOT NULL,
    StatusCode CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    AsOf DATE NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (EmpID, AsOf)
)

INSERT INTO #sample_Data (EmpID, StatusCode, AsOf) VALUES 
(12345,'J','20140630'),
(12345,'J','20140731'),
(12345,'J','20140829'),
(12345,'J','20140930'),
(12345,'G','20141031'),
(12345,'G','20141128'),
(12345,'G','20141231'),
(12345,'G','20150130'),
(12345,'G','20150227'),
(12345,'M','20150330'),
(12345,'M','20150430'),
(12345,'M','20150529'),
(12345,'M','20150630'),
(12345,'G','20150731'),
(12345,'G','20150831'),
(12345,'G','20150930'),
(12345,'G','20151030'),
(12345,'G','20151130')
```

**Answer:**

This answer will work assuming that you are on SQL Server 2012 or later. The query below takes advantage of [Window Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) such as [`lag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) and [`sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) to identify where the islands begin and assign an `IslandNbr` to them. On the final outer query, there is a `datediff` calculation to determine the first day of that month, and a [`eomonth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) function to determine the last day of the month for their corresponding input `AsOf` dates.

```
select b.EmpID
, b.StatusCode
, cast(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, min(b.AsOf)), 0)as date) as [Start]
, eomonth(max(b.AsOf)) as [End]
from (
    select a.EmpID
    , a.StatusCode
    , a.AsOf
    , sum(a.IslandBegin) over (partition by a.EmpID, a.StatusCode order by a.AsOf) as IslandNbr
    from (
        select d.EmpID
        , d.StatusCode
        , d.AsOf
        , case when datediff(month, lag(d.AsOf, 1, null) over (partition by d.EmpID, d.StatusCode order by d.AsOf asc), d.AsOf) = 1 then 0 else 1 end as IslandBegin
        from #sample_Data as d
        ) as a
    ) as b
group by b.EmpID
, b.StatusCode
, b.IslandNbr
order by 3
```

**Output:**

The output matches the expected results exactly.

```
+-------+------------+------------+------------+
| EmpID | StatusCode |   Start    |    End     |
+-------+------------+------------+------------+
| 12345 | J          | 2014-06-01 | 2014-09-30 |
| 12345 | G          | 2014-10-01 | 2015-02-28 |
| 12345 | M          | 2015-03-01 | 2015-06-30 |
| 12345 | G          | 2015-07-01 | 2015-11-30 |
+-------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
/*
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    EmpID int NOT NULL,
    StatusCode CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    AsOf DATE NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (EmpID, AsOf)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (EmpID, StatusCode, AsOf) VALUES 
(12345,'J','20140630'),
(12345,'J','20140731'),
(12345,'J','20140829'),
(12345,'J','20140930'),
(12345,'G','20141031'),
(12345,'G','20141128'),
(12345,'G','20141231'),
(12345,'G','20150130'),
(12345,'G','20150227'),
(12345,'M','20150330'),
(12345,'M','20150430'),
(12345,'M','20150529'),
(12345,'M','20150630'),
(12345,'G','20150731'),
(12345,'G','20150831'),
(12345,'G','20150930'),
(12345,'G','20151030'),
(12345,'G','20151130')
*/

SELECT DISTINCT Q2.EmpID, Q2.StatusCode, 
    DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,'20000101',Q2.FirstAsOf),'20000101') AS StartDate,
    DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,'20000101',Q2.LastAsOf)+1,'20000101')) AS EndDate
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        MIN(Q1.AsOf) OVER (PARTITION BY Q1.EmpID,Q1.StatusCode,Q1.Dif) AS FirstAsOf,
        MAX(Q1.AsOf) OVER (PARTITION BY Q1.EmpID,Q1.StatusCode,Q1.Dif) AS LastAsOf
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.EmpID ORDER BY t.AsOf)
            -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.EmpID,t.StatusCode ORDER BY t.AsOf) AS Dif
        FROM dbo.Table1 t
    ) Q1
) Q2
ORDER BY EmpID, StartDate
```