# Convert Repeating Values to Intervals in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have the following scenario:

Multiple devices send their installed operating system `OS` version every day, regardless of a change in the version or not. For example, in below `Table1`, `Device_A` sends the same value `OS_1` for two consecutive days, until the version is changed on the third day. Similar situation for `Device_B`:

**Table1**:

| Device | TimeStamp | OSVersion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Device_A | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | OS_1 |
| Device_A | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | OS_1 |
| Device_B | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | OS_1.1 |
| Device_B | 2023-05-02 00:00:00 | OS_1.2 |
| Device_A | 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | OS_2 |
| Device_A | 2023-01-04 00:00:00 | OS_2 |

This table is filled with millions of devices, so I would like to convert this table, into another structure, that is for each device we have the intervals (from, to) within which a specific OS version is installed. `Table2` below illustrates the desired schema:

**Table2:**

| Device | OSVersion | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Device_A | OS_1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-02 23:59:59 |
| Device_A | OS_2 | 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | 2999-12-31 23:59:59 |
| Device_B | OS_1.1 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-01 23:59:59 |
| Device_B | OS_1.2 | 2023-05-02 00:00:00 | 2999-12-31 23:59:59 |

Note: even a device is normally upgraded, but it could also be downgraded to the older OS version.

The solution should be on `Databricks` delta tables, using `Pyspark` or `Databricks SQL`

Comment: Check [gaps-and-islands](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgaps-and-islands%5D+range) tag - there are a bazillion of questions similar to yours. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712708/date-range-from-single-date) looks almost exact. Most solutions are using standard window functions and will work fine in Databricks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Range From Single Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712708/date-range-from-single-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to do it with `pyspark`:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql import Window
>>> 
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
>>> 
>>> dt = lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
>>>   [("Device_A", dt("2023-01-01 00:00:00"), "OS_1"),
>>>   ("Device_A", dt("2023-01-02 00:00:00"), "OS_1"),
>>>   ("Device_B", dt("2023-05-01 00:00:00"), "OS_1.1"),
>>>   ("Device_B", dt("2023-05-02 00:00:00"), "OS_1.2"),
>>>   ("Device_A", dt("2023-01-03 00:00:00"), "OS_2"),
>>>   ("Device_A", dt("2023-01-04 00:00:00"), "OS_2"),
>>>   ("Device_A", dt("2023-01-05 00:00:00"), "OS_1"),
>>>   ("Device_A", dt("2023-01-06 00:00:00"), "OS_1")],
>>>   ["device", "timestamp", "os"]
>>> )
>>> df.show()
+--------+-------------------+------+
|  device|          timestamp|    os|
+--------+-------------------+------+
|Device_A|2023-01-01 00:00:00|  OS_1|
|Device_A|2023-01-02 00:00:00|  OS_1|
|Device_B|2023-05-01 00:00:00|OS_1.1|
|Device_B|2023-05-02 00:00:00|OS_1.2|
|Device_A|2023-01-03 00:00:00|  OS_2|
|Device_A|2023-01-04 00:00:00|  OS_2|
|Device_A|2023-01-05 00:00:00|  OS_1|
|Device_A|2023-01-06 00:00:00|  OS_1|
+--------+-------------------+------+
```

Using [windows](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html) is the way to do it:

```py
>>> window = Window().partitionBy("device").orderBy("timestamp")
```

We have to split the rows in groups based on `os` and ordered by `timestamp`.

```py
>>> df = df.withColumn("_os_lag", F.lag("os").over(window))
>>> df.show()
+--------+-------------------+------+-------+
|  device|          timestamp|    os|_os_lag|
+--------+-------------------+------+-------+
|Device_A|2023-01-01 00:00:00|  OS_1|   null|
|Device_A|2023-01-02 00:00:00|  OS_1|   OS_1|
|Device_A|2023-01-03 00:00:00|  OS_2|   OS_1|
|Device_A|2023-01-04 00:00:00|  OS_2|   OS_2|
|Device_A|2023-01-05 00:00:00|  OS_1|   OS_2|
|Device_A|2023-01-06 00:00:00|  OS_1|   OS_1|
|Device_B|2023-05-01 00:00:00|OS_1.1|   null|
|Device_B|2023-05-02 00:00:00|OS_1.2| OS_1.1|
+--------+-------------------+------+-------+
```

Comparing `os` with `_os_lag` we can detect `os` changes:

```py
>>> df = df.withColumn("_os_change", F.when(~df.os.eqNullSafe(df._os_lag), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)))
>>> df.show()
+--------+-------------------+------+-------+----------+
|  device|          timestamp|    os|_os_lag|_os_change|
+--------+-------------------+------+-------+----------+
|Device_A|2023-01-01 00:00:00|  OS_1|   null|         1|
|Device_A|2023-01-02 00:00:00|  OS_1|   OS_1|         0|
|Device_A|2023-01-03 00:00:00|  OS_2|   OS_1|         1|
|Device_A|2023-01-04 00:00:00|  OS_2|   OS_2|         0|
|Device_A|2023-01-05 00:00:00|  OS_1|   OS_2|         1|
|Device_A|2023-01-06 00:00:00|  OS_1|   OS_1|         0|
|Device_B|2023-05-01 00:00:00|OS_1.1|   null|         1|
|Device_B|2023-05-02 00:00:00|OS_1.2| OS_1.1|         1|
+--------+-------------------+------+-------+----------+
```

Now we do the cumulative sum of `_os_change` over the defined window to split each device in groups (on each group all have the same `os`, and the groups are ordered by `timestamp`):

```py
>>> df = df.withColumn("_group", F.sum("_os_change").over(window))
>>> df.show()
+--------+-------------------+------+-------+----------+------+
|  device|          timestamp|    os|_os_lag|_os_change|_group|
+--------+-------------------+------+-------+----------+------+
|Device_A|2023-01-01 00:00:00|  OS_1|   null|         1|     1|
|Device_A|2023-01-02 00:00:00|  OS_1|   OS_1|         0|     1|
|Device_A|2023-01-03 00:00:00|  OS_2|   OS_1|         1|     2|
|Device_A|2023-01-04 00:00:00|  OS_2|   OS_2|         0|     2|
|Device_A|2023-01-05 00:00:00|  OS_1|   OS_2|         1|     3|
|Device_A|2023-01-06 00:00:00|  OS_1|   OS_1|         0|     3|
|Device_B|2023-05-01 00:00:00|OS_1.1|   null|         1|     1|
|Device_B|2023-05-02 00:00:00|OS_1.2| OS_1.1|         1|     2|
+--------+-------------------+------+-------+----------+------+
```

The last thing we have to do is get the maximum and minimum `timestamp` for each device group:

```py
>>> df.groupBy("device", "os", "_group").agg(
>>>    F.min("timestamp").name("start"),
>>>    F.max("timestamp").name("end")
>>> ).show()
+--------+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  device|    os|_group|              start|                end|
+--------+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|Device_A|  OS_1|     1|2023-01-01 00:00:00|2023-01-02 00:00:00|
|Device_A|  OS_2|     2|2023-01-03 00:00:00|2023-01-04 00:00:00|
|Device_A|  OS_1|     3|2023-01-05 00:00:00|2023-01-06 00:00:00|
|Device_B|OS_1.1|     1|2023-05-01 00:00:00|2023-05-01 00:00:00|
|Device_B|OS_1.2|     2|2023-05-02 00:00:00|2023-05-02 00:00:00|
+--------+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @cruzlorite you can also use below pyspark code.
Below is the sample data used.

[image]

```
data = [
("Device_A", "2023-01-01 00:00:00", "OS_1"),
("Device_A", "2023-01-02 00:00:00", "OS_1"),
("Device_A", "2023-01-03 00:00:00", "OS_1"),
("Device_B", "2023-05-01 00:00:00", "OS_1.1"),
("Device_B", "2023-05-02 00:00:00", "OS_1.2"),
("Device_A", "2023-01-04 00:00:00", "OS_2"),
("Device_A", "2023-01-05 00:00:00", "OS_2"),
("Device_C", "2023-01-06 00:00:00", "OS_2"),
("Device_C", "2023-01-08 00:00:00", "OS_3")
]

columns = ["Device", "TimeStamp", "OSVersion"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df = df.withColumn("TimeStamp", col("TimeStamp").cast("timestamp"))
display(df)
```

code

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("Device").orderBy("TimeStamp")
df2 = df.withColumn("NextOSVersion", lag("OSVersion",-1).over(window_spec))
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("Device","OSVersion").orderBy("TimeStamp")
df2 = df2.withColumn("StartTime", fn.min("TimeStamp").over(window_spec))
df2 = df2.withColumn("EndTime",when(col("NextOSVersion").isNull(),fn.lit("2999-12-31 23:59:59").cast("timestamp")).otherwise(fn.max("TimeStamp").over(window_spec)+fn.expr('INTERVAL  23  HOURS')+fn.expr('INTERVAL  59  MINUTE')+fn.expr('INTERVAL  59  SECOND')))
df2 = df2.filter((col("NextOSVersion").isNull()) | (col("NextOSVersion")!=col("OSVersion"))).drop("NextOSVersion","TimeStamp")
display(df2)
```

Output:

[image]